# Unable to delete a k8s namespace

Tags: kubernetes

I wanted to delete a k8s namespace but I get this error back and still didn't realize how to resolve it. Can anyone please help?

> Error from server (InternalError): Internal error occurred: failed
> calling webhook "namespace.validators.kubedb.com": the server is
> currently unable to handle the request

Answer (score 2):

With the info provided in the question, the error is pointing that there is a `validation webhook` configured in `validators` namespace and this `webhook` is not responding or missing.

> Error from server (InternalError): Internal error occurred: **failed
> calling webhook "namespace.validators.kubedb.com": the server is
> currently unable to handle the request**

You can check the validation wehbhook by running:

```
kubectl get validatingwebhookconfigurations.admissionregistration.k8s.io
```

From the below output, it is clear that your service do not have any endpoint(pods) to forward the requests.

```
kubectl get ep -n validators
No resources found in validators namespace.
```

To fix this, you need to check the validation webhook and fix or delete it.

As OP provided the output of `endpoints` in the validator namespace, there is no endpoint associated with the service. In such case, the behavior seems to be expected. To help the OP to debug the issue, here is a simple demo showing the relation of service/pods/endpoints.

// following is the pod that will be exposed by the service.

```
kubectl get pod my-pod -owide --show-labels
NAME     READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP            NODE            NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES   LABELS
my-pod   1/1     Running   0          22s   10.233.72.6   kube-worker-3   <none>           <none>            app=nginx
```

// note that, there is no service and endpoint associated with the pod is present

```
k get svc -l app=nginx
No resources found in default namespace.

k get ep -l app=nginx
No resources found in default namespace.
```

// exposing the pod by a service called my-pod-svc

```
k expose pod my-pod --name my-pod-svc --port 80
service/my-pod-svc exposed
```

//now note the service, endpoint and their IPs.

```
k get svc -l app=nginx
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
my-pod-svc   ClusterIP   10.233.26.82   <none>        80/TCP    21s
    
k get ep -l app=nginx
NAME         ENDPOINTS        AGE
my-pod-svc   10.233.72.6:80   7s
```

// trying to connect to the pod via service(my-pod-svc) IP

```
kubectl run tmp-shell --restart=Never --rm -i --tty --image busybox -- wget -nv 10.233.26.82 -o -
Connecting to 10.233.26.82 (10.233.26.82:80)
saving to 'index.html'
index.html           100% |********************************|   615  0:00:00 ETA
'index.html' saved
pod "tmp-shell" deleted
```

Now deleting the pod(my-pod) that is exposed by the service my-pod-svc. This also means, deleting the endpoint of the service.

```
 k delete  pod my-pod --force --grace-period 0
warning: Immediate deletion does not wait for confirmation that the running resource has been terminated. The resource may continue to run on the cluster indefinitely.
pod "my-pod" force deleted
```

Checking the endpoint status now:

```
k get ep -l app=nginx
NAME         ENDPOINTS   AGE
my-pod-svc   <none>      11m
```

Now trying to connect to the my-pod-svc service:

```
kubectl run tmp-shell --restart=Never --rm -i --tty --image busybox -- wget -nv 10.233.26.82 -o -
If you don't see a command prompt, try pressing enter.
wget: can't connect to remote host (10.233.26.82): Connection refused
pod "tmp-shell" deleted
pod default/tmp-shell terminated (Error)
```

Comment: I checked it and the kubedb.com exists

Comment: Now verify  its healthy and responding to curl.

Comment: Create a test ns and delete it. Check its endpoints. Then check the logs of endpoints when new ns is deleted..

Comment: would you please help with exact command lines? I am new to k8s

Comment: a test ns is already created and I just would like to delete it

Comment: `kubectl get ep -n validators` , this command will give you the endpoints of the service. Eg: pods exposed by the service.

Comment: Please keep adding the output of requested data in the question.  For any further help.

Comment: Here is the output of `kubectl get ep -n validators` > `No resources found in validators namespace.`

Comment: This explains well that your service kubedb.com is not properly configured,  a service need one or more endpoints to forward the data received.

Comment: Please delete the validation webhooks. Use the command in the answer to get the name of the webhook.